# Mobile mode picture doesnt load full

Tags: javascript, java, html

Hello i have a problem with my website.. the mobile mode right side doesnt show full width/    [Click Here to my website](http://studioarcadis.com/projekti13.html)

Here is a pic of my problem [IMAGE LINK](https://ibb.co/hZotkc).  do i have to edit the bxslider.js
maybe to change the width or something
i have change this code

```
            slider.viewport.css({
            width: '155%',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            position: 'relative'
        });
```

Know do i have to make it 100% but i dont want to lose the picture resolution.. can anyone help me fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have fixed it i just have to make the width 100%

Here is the code

```
            slider.viewport.css({
        width: '100%',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative'
    });
```